# Typescript does not like || between two values which may be undefined

Tags: typescript

I've got this construct in Typescript, and Typescript does not like it. It seems it is not able to realize that one of date_deposited and date_requested have a value in the true part of the ternary.

```
  const date =
    date_deposited || date_requested ? new Date(date_deposited || date_requested) : null
```

Other solutions I can think of seem overly complicated and over-engineered. Does anyone have simple way of solving this?

Answer (score 0):

did you try using parenthesis like below

```
 const date =
    (date_deposited || date_requested) ? new Date(date_deposited || date_requested) : null
```

Comment: Yes, I did. It does not work.